# getting an error with org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

public class SecUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;


    public SecUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

this code is throwing an error any help?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project modular: Compilation failure [ERROR]
>   /var/local/modular/src/main/java/demo/SecUserDetails.java:[6,8]
>   demo.SecUserDetails is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method isEnabled() in
>   org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

Comment: `Compilation failure [ERROR] /var/local/modular/src/main/java/demo/SecUserDetails.java:[6,8] demo.SecUserDetails is not abstract and does not override abstract method isEnabled() in org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`, doesn't this suggest that you should override `isEnabled()`?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html Implement all those `get*` and `is*` methods. You can also, extend spring's `User` class http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html

Comment: thanks guys both your answers helped.